# Genymotion android 5 network error

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I have downloaded a new genymotion android 5 ova file, and imported it to virtual box successfully. When I start the new device, it takes a long time and shows this error:

> Unable to connect to the virtual device. Genymotion will now close.
> Please check VirtualBox network configuration.
>
> for more information please refer to :
> https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#collapse-nostart

I read the troubleshot followed the error message. My network configuration is correct as the instruction. (The address is 192.168.56.100/24, and DHCP is the same rang. Also other virtual devices correctly start.)

I ran the vm with the VirtualBox and got this error:

> init : cannot find '/system/bin/install-recovery.sh' , disabling 'flash_recovery'
>
> IP Management : 192.168.56.101
>
> failed to execute /sbin/v86d make sure that the v86d helper is
>
> installed and executable Getting VBE info block failed (eax=0x4f00,err=-2)
>
> vbe_init() failed with -22

What should I do ?

Comment: Do you have two network adapters configured in VirtualBox for the VM? Adapter 1 should be host-only (for host control) and Adapter 2 should be NAT (for Internet access).

Comment: Yes, exactly is the same in the VM Setting.But except of other adapters there is only one network adapter in my Windows network connection tagged "VirtualBox" named "VirtualBox Host-Only Network". Needs more?